# VIPER architecture with generic protocols

Tags: swift, generics, viper-architecture

I got an interesting question about the VIPER architecture and Generics protocol.

It seems that the Presenter and Interactor communicates a lot, (for fetching and receiving data), but the "Output" functions of the Interactor will always be the same

Something like:

```
func dataFetched(object: JSONObject)
```

And if you have 10 modules you'll have 10 times this function with only the JSONObject that change...

Is that possible to use something like

```
protocol Ouput {
  associatedType Object
  func dataFetched(object: Object)
}
```

And choose the type of Object in the presenter?

Comment: Nope, that's not possible. It's actually one of the problems of VIPER - the abstraction results in rather big amount of protocol code which is also often duplicated. You can create parent protocols though. E.g. `dataFetched` will generally also have a pair function `dataFailed(error:)` and that can be abstracted to a parent protocol.

Comment: Hmm, Kinda disapointing, I wanted to avoid a plenty of protocols.

Yeah my protocol actually have 3 functions

didFetch(object: Object)
didFetch(objects: [Objects])
didFail(error: Error?)

But I don't want to have an output protocol for every models, cause it'll lead to have N times the didFetch/didFail functions..

But if not possible, I'll do another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If JSONObject is an Entity presenter should not know about it. Instead, interactor should return pleomorphic type that can be converted to a ViewModel. And then presenter can pass this ViewModel to the view. So interactor output could look like:

```
func didFetched(object: ViewModelConvertible)
```

Comment: Yes JSONObject will be models used across the app.
So I should create a class above all my entities and use that type instead of associatedType/typealias ?

Comment: But there's no viewModel into VIPER architecture.
Presenter directly communicate with the ViewController itself with method like

view?.update(with: JSONObject)

or

view?.displayAlert(for: error).

Comment: In VIPER models or entities, can`t be used across the app. Because changes in the entities should not affect presenter. ViewModel in VIPER is a simple struct without any logic. Presenter passes to view this ViewModels and view just sets its controls with values from this ViewModel

Comment: But by adding a ViewModel you add another layer nah?
So the conversion of ViewModelConvertible to the entity will be done in that viewModel ?

Comment: The associated type could be problematic interactor needs to hold output as a property, so you will need to use type erasure

Comment: In Swit conversion to the ViewModel could be done in the extension

Comment: Hmmm I like your idea.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: The whole purpose of VIPER is the creation of independent layers, and the best way achieve it in Swift, I think,  is a polymorphism with protocols

Comment: @AndreyVolobuev aka. static polymorphism